# Sicklms200 model for Gazebo

Tags: gazebo-model

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Anyone knows where I can find a Sicklms200 model for Gazebo 1.6. I see that in the old versions was a model included but know it is not in the gazebo/models repository. I found the old sicklms200.model and the .mesh file but I do not know where I have to put them in order to work.

I would appreciate any help

The problem is that I got an siclms200.model file that looks like this:

<model:physical name="default_sicklms200_model"
xmlns:model="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#model"

xmlns:controller="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#controller"

xmlns:interface="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#interface"

xmlns:sensor="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#sensor"

xmlns:body="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#body"

xmlns:geom="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#geom"

xmlns:joint="http://playerstage.sourceforge.net/gazebo/xmlschema/#joint"

> 

< x y z> 0 0.0 0.0 < /x y z>

< r p y> 0 0 0< /r p y>

< canonicalBody> laser_body < /canonicalBody >

< body:box name="laser_body" >

```
<xyz>0.0 0.0 0.0</xyz>

<rpy>0.0 0.0 0.0</rpy>

< geom:box name="laser_geom1" >

  <xyz>0.0 0.0 0.0</xyz>

  <rpy>0 0 90</rpy>

  <size>0.15 0.15 0.2</size>

  <mass>0.01</mass>

  <visual>

    <scale>0.07 0.07 0.1</scale>

    <mesh>sicklms200.mesh</mesh>

    <material>Gazebo/Blue</material>

  </visual>

  <visual>

    <rpy>0 0 0</rpy>

    <size>0.12 0.12 0.18</size>

    <mesh>unit_cylinder</mesh>

    <material>Gazebo/Black</material>

  </visual>

</geom:box>

<sensor:ray name="laser_1">

  <rayCount>180</rayCount>

  <rangeCount>361</rangeCount>

  <origin>0.05 0.0 0</origin>

  <displayRays>fan</displayRays>

  <minAngle>-90</minAngle>

  <maxAngle>90</maxAngle>

  <minRange>0.1</minRange>

  <maxRange>8</maxRange>

  <resRange>.1</resRange>

  <alwaysActive>true</alwaysActive>

  <controller:sicklms200_laser name="laser_controller_1">

    <interface:laser name="laser_iface_0"/>

    <interface:fiducial name="fiducial_iface_0"/>

  </controller:sicklms200_laser>

</sensor:ray>
```

</body:box>

</model:physical>

And is not quite the same as the .sdf file for example from hokuyo laser. I don't know how to make it work, I have tried to change it to a sdf file format but still I can not make it work because I have a sicklms200.mesh file not a sicklms200.dae file and it gives me an error and does not work. I don't know why is this.

I don't know what is the best way of approaching the problem. I don't know how to update the model or how to make it work and I don't know where I can find some information. I am a bit lost.

I would appreciate any help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2595/sicklms200-model-for-gazebo/) by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-04-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi,

as standard Gazebo uses the ~/.gazebo folder for the models and meshes. You can put the model there, and just drag and drop it in the world if it is compatible.

You could check the [tutorials](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials) page, and then update with other questions you may have.

Cheers,
Andrei

---

Originally posted by [AndreiHaidu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/87/andreihaidu/) with karma: 2108 on 2013-04-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [agonzamart](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/250/agonzamart/) on 2013-05-08**:
Hi thank you for the answer, but is not quite working. The problem is that the file I found is a .model file not a .sdf file I explained above...

**Comment by [iche033](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/58/iche033/) on 2013-05-10**:
You could just build your own sick lms model using simple shapes provided by Gazebo. It's just a few boxes and cylinders. The .model format is outdated, so as Andrei suggested, look through the tutorial page to learn how to build a model in sdf format.